# Niemytzki continious function

Tags: general-topology

In Wiki, they state that this function, whose image is in [0,1] and that is defined on X with the Niemyetzki topology, is continuous:
[image]
Therefore, the preimages of sets of the form $(x-r, x+r) $ with $ x \in R $ and $r>0$  (that are exactly the open sets in R with the standard topology), have to be of the form:

[image]
I don't see how the preimages does satisfy this, like $(x_0,0)$ will be in non of the preimages as zero is not in any open set. Therefore, y has to be positive and the preimages are balls that are contained in X. That is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the preimages of open intervals don’t have to be of the form $U_r(x_0,y_0)$: they just have to be unions of sets of that form. But that’s the hard way to check that $f_{r,x_0}$ is continuous. Let $H=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R\times\Bbb R:y>0\}$. It’s not too hard to check that $f_{r,x_0}\upharpoonright H$ is continuous in the Euclidean topology on $H$ and hence in the Niemytzki topology, since they agree on $H$, so all that remains is to check that $f_{r,x_0}$ is continuous on $\Bbb R\times\{0\}$. This is also pretty easy if you use the fact that the Niemytzki plane $X$ is first countable and check that if $\langle p_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to\langle x,0\rangle$ in $X$, , then $\langle f_{r,x_0}(p_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $0$ if $x=x_0$ and to $1$ otherwise.

(Those functions might be worth adding to the English Wikipedia article, too; I’ll have to think about it.)

Comment: why do we only consider H as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ ( f is continuous also on R with y>0)

Comment: @user23657: I considered $H$ separately because it’s trivial to see that these functions are continuous on $H$. That means that the only real work involved is checking that they are continuous at points on the $x$-axis, but that also turns out to be quite easy.

Comment: i have to more presice, i mean why not choose $H*= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} :y>0\}$ as f is continuous there as well for the same reasons, why do you choose H to be countable instead?

Comment: @user23657: Because for some reason I was thinking of a version of the Niemytzki plane in which only those points are used. I’ll change it to the standard version now.

Comment: visually i dont see why the Niemytzki topology is on H the same as the standard topology, because former has also kinda cutted balls/ semicircles as we intersect with X. These semicircles, as points with x=0 are contained in X, seems to be closed ( with respect to the standard topology) on the bottom

Comment: @user23657: Take any basic open set in the Niemytzki topology: its intersection with $H$ is open in the Euclidean topology. That’s true even if it’s one of the tangent disk nbhds: that one point where it’s not open in the standard topology isn’t in $H$.